Transparency in PyQt widgets & VTK
I have a few widgets such as a QLabel and QPushbuttons hovering over a VTK scene like below. As you can see, when I add a border-radius to the them, the remaining area around the labels or buttons is black. I would instead like to see the VTK scene behind them. How can I achieve this?

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from vtkmodules.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
import vtk

class VTKSphereApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("VTK Sphere in PyQt5")
        self.resize(800, 600)

        # Central Widget
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Create and configure QLabel
        self.label = QLabel("Notice the corners of the label", self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 5px solid purple; border-radius:15px")
        self.label.setGeometry(10, 10, 200, 50)
        
        # VTK Widget
        self.vtk_widget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(central_widget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.vtk_widget)

        # VTK Renderer and Sphere
        self.renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.vtk_widget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.renderer)

        # Sphere
        sphere_source = vtk.vtkSphereSource()
        sphere_source.SetRadius(5.0)
        sphere_source.SetThetaResolution(50)
        sphere_source.SetPhiResolution(50)

        # Sphere Mapper
        mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        mapper.SetInputConnection(sphere_source.GetOutputPort())

        # Sphere Actor
        actor = vtk.vtkActor()
        actor.SetMapper(mapper)
        self.renderer.AddActor(actor)

        # Background Color
        self.renderer.SetBackground(0.1, 0.2, 0.4)

        # Initialize VTK Rendering
        self.vtk_widget.GetRenderWindow().Render()
        self.vtk_widget.Initialize()

        button1 = QPushButton("Button 1", self)
        button2 = QPushButton("Button 2", self)
        button1.setStyleSheet("color:white; border: 4px solid red; border-radius:15px")
        button2.setStyleSheet("color:white; border: 4px solid red; border-radius:15px")    
        button1.setGeometry(350, 500, 100, 40)
        button2.setGeometry(450, 500, 100, 40)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = VTKSphereApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

I have adjusted the background to transparent but it did not work
